# Which AWS services Netflix is using?

Tags: amazon-web-services, netflix, spring-cloud-netflix

I started looking to some AWS training courses, and as I'm a Java Developer, I'm so interested with the Netflix OSS (Spring Cloud,..) and its own infrastructure.

As AWS has many many services for various uses, I wish to know which services of AWS NetFlix is using and its use case.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackshare is a website which gives info on the technology stacks that a number of companies use and Netflix is listed there:

https://stackshare.io/netflix/netflix

Netflix have also published more detail on open source tools which they use here:

https://netflix.github.io/